# ReferenceError: Chart is not defined - chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

Is there a bug with Chart.js? Every time I add any of the graphs at Chart.js to my website I get an error, but when I used the graph as stand-alone program it runs smoothly without errors. I am using HTML5.

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Rice Consumption</title>
      <script src='Chart.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <canvas id="rice" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

      <script>
        var riceData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
        datasets :
         [
            {
              fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
              strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
              pointColor : "#fff",
              pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
              data : [203000,15600,99000,25100,30500,24700]
            }
         ]
        }

          var rice = document.getElementById('rice').getContext('2d');
               new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**SOLVED**: I just decoupled the script from the canvas element (made another file for the script to execute its function).

Updated HTML:

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Rice Consumption</title>
      <script src='Chart.min.js'></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <canvas id="rice" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
      <script src='Chart.min.js'></script>
      <script src='rice.js'></script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

New JavaScript file:

```
var riceData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
            strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
            pointColor : "#fff",
            pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
            data : [203000,15600,99000,25100,30500,24700]
        }
    ]
}

var rice = document.getElementById('rice').getContext('2d');
new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);
```

Comment: Please add some details as to how exactly you linked ChartJS. Where’s the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Thanks! This seems weird, indeed…

Comment: Is “Chart.min.js” in the same folder as the HTML?

Comment: include your JS with the correct type. <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.min.js"></script>
What is displayed in your console ? any 404 on your Chart.min.js file?

Comment: @SamiX the `type` attribute on `<script>` tags is optional. It shouldn’t matter.

Comment: Chart.min.js is in the same folder.
404?none.

Comment: Please, if you have answered your own question, post an answer as opposed to editing the *question*. (Also, it may help if you update the question a bit with more details on how to repro things.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is a working jsfiddle of your code: 
`new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);` 
http://jsfiddle.net/mahmalsami/jqcthmyo/ 
So the problem is definitively coming from your external Chart.min.js inclusion 

You may find a 404 on your js get. Please make sure you're linking to the correct js folder. (try accessing your localhost/Chart.min.js to see if you can access to your file)

Comment: I have used <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> but my bootstrap template is not working. <script src="build/js/custom.min.js"></script> , this tag seems to be disabled. Could you please suggest me any ideas for enable it?

Comment: @FRECEENAFRANCIS, example using your <script> https://jsfiddle.net/mahmalsami/mxre34b0/6/

Comment: The fiddle is not working now for some reason

Answer (score 14):

I was also getting same error. To fix this I moved the chart script into separate graph.js file.

Still I was getting same error. Which is fixed later when I put  tag in following order before end of  tag as shown below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/graph.js"></script>
</body>
```

The page look like this:
[image]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error. To solve the problem, you have to include the chart.js library correctly as follows:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

1) I tried `Chart.js` downloaded from `Chartjs.org`.
But, it's not working.

2) Try to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js">
</script>
```

Working good.

Comment: New way of adding it is via the CDN:

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

This error shows you did not install the plugin that helps run the Chart.js library on the HTML page.
if that script is not present, this error shows which version you used Chart.js then that version script is pasted in it.

> `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`

It will help you solve the problem. It comes in many versions like

> `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The issue is, `chart.min.js` is actually trying to "import" stuff, while i'm using plain JS there's not "import" in my case ... so it didn't work. the version of `libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.min.js` or `Chart.min.js` works - because this is a compiled suitable JS file that doesn't import - just bundled with everything, so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this intermittently on Ruby on Rails 5, like I was, the issue was to do with Turbolinks, which I disabled. Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

Have run into this problem two times with Chartjs and solved both by using setTimeout to delay the call of the function that is causing the error.

Comment: While this may work, it's not that robust of a solution -- changes in how long various bits of code take could cause this to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit late to answer this question, but the way it worked for me, having the same problem, is to put the CDN after the code to graph, put it before, you can't call an object without declaring it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Code to graphic...
    // Check Chart.js Doc (v3.9.1)
    // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a small timeout before chart creation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
     var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"],
            datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#2ecc71",
                        "#3498db",
                        "#95a5a6",
                        "#9b59b6",
                        "#f1c40f",
                        "#e74c3c",
                        "#34495e"
                    ],
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
                }]
        }
    });
```

},100);
});

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in my vue js application.
Solved it by registering the LinearScale component

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend, LinearScale);
```

Answer (score -3):

This is very basic error which should be taken care off at very start of the document.
Make sure you properly install chartjs library whether you want it like cdn/npm pacakge,etc. follow the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).