# Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined - Chart.js in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am creating my control panel and liked to create a chart to show data from my table but is giving me this error.
**Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined**
I do not know much about javascript. If anyone could help me grateful.

**Html**

```
<div class="box-body no-padding">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="610"></canvas>
</div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

**My script**

```
<script>

    var PieChart = [
            {
                value: 40,
                color:"#fcc79e"
            },
            {
                value : 30,
                color : "#beefd2"
            },
            {
                value : 90,
                color : "#ffddfb"
            }

        ];

var myPieChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Pie(PieChart);

            </script>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785623/referenceerror-chart-is-not-defined-chartjs

Comment: I tried with that complete code that works and gives me this error on the last line
new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);

Comment: try code i have posted in answer

Comment: I tried with your code 
http://jsfiddle.net/mahmalsami/jqcthmyo/

Answer (score 1):

Update your library. I have test this and working.

```
 <div class="box-body no-padding">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="610"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js" ></script>
<script>

    var PieChart = [
            {
                value: 40,
                color:"#fcc79e"
            },
            {
                value : 30,
                color : "#beefd2"
            },
            {
                value : 90,
                color : "#ffddfb"
            }

        ];

var myPieChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Pie(PieChart);

            </script>
```

Comment: I'm building the site in laravel and it gives me this error
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is

Comment: how to do it in yii2? can you please see my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255144/yii2-chart-is-not-defined)?