# How can I import external libraries into the code sandbox?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I've been trying to import a library called chart.js to the code sandbox on slate, but even after I read the documentation I was quite doubtful about how the import system works inside the code sandbox, I wish someone could explain me in detail how I do the import of the library, how to call it in the LIBRARY LOCATIONS field and also how to call it in the JAVASCRIPT field inside the code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step-by-step:

- Drag-and-drop the JS file in a project or folder of your choice (not in a dataset !)
- Choose `Upload as a raw file without modifying the extension (recommended)` when prompted
- Let it upload
- You will see the JS file in the project or folder you uploaded it to, you can then select the line representing your file and this should open a right panel, where you can find the path to this file e.g. `/myproject/myfolder/myJSlibrary.js`
- In Slate, add a Code-Sandbox widget
- In the configuration of the code Sandbox widget, find at the bottom the `LIBRARY LOCATIONS` section (see [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/widgets-advanced/#javascript-tab))
- Past the path you found earlier, in an array, like `["/myproject/myfolder/myJSlibrary.js"]`

If you need multiple libraries, you should have something like:
`["/myproject/myfolder/myJSlibrary.js", "/myproject/myfolder/myOtherJSlibrary.js"]`

For the library usage, it depends of course of which kind of problem you hit. But here is a minimal working example.

Library from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js)
Below example from [official page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html)

HTML

```html
<canvas id="acquisitions"></canvas>
```

JS

```js
  const data = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2011, count: 20 },
    { year: 2012, count: 15 },
    { year: 2013, count: 25 },
    { year: 2014, count: 22 },
    { year: 2015, count: 30 },
    { year: 2016, count: 28 },
  ];

new Chart(
    document.getElementById('acquisitions'),
    {
      type: 'bar',
      options: {
        animation: false,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      data: {
        labels: data.map(row => row.year),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Acquisitions by year',
            data: data.map(row => row.count)
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  );
```

Note: You can see errors related to your lib in the `Console` tab of your browser's devtools panel.

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks, but I still have a doubt, you used version 2.4.0 of chart.js, is there a specific reason, I tried to do the test with a more updated version and it doesn't work, is there a specific reason why you used this version?

Comment: It's the first version I found .. so no reason really :) Which version doesn't work for you ?

Comment: The latest one was not working when I tested it, I don't believe it was an import error because I tested it with 2.4.0 and it worked perfectly

Comment: Indeed the latest is not working, but it seems to be a general issue with Chart.js. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084946/12186528 for instance. Download the "chart.umd.min.js" instead of "chart.min.js" from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js. For me it works with the 4.2.1 chart.umd.min.js :)